# How can I deactivate mouse motion (<Motion-1>) on windows taskbar while I am dragging my frameless window?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

I am working on a Frameless window for modern GUI with Tkinter. I have implemented a drag window feature but It is also working when window is behind of the taskbar, it is a big problem when I am trying to recover my window from behind of taskbar. So I want to disable the drag feature when the mouse reaches on taskbar's border.

```py
  def drag(event):
      act = str(event.type)
      if act == 'Motion':
            global _app
            #_app is a reference to root in other py file
            t = _app.geometry().split('+')[1:]
            xval = int(t[0])
            yval = int(t[1])
            _app.geometry('+'+
                          str(xval + event.x -400)+
                          '+'+str(yval + event.y -20))
            #window size is fixed i.e. 800x480
```

Comment: What platform are you on? "taskbar" can mean different things on different platforms.

Comment: I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you makes a window border-less using overrideredirect() method, then this method says to operating system's windows manager to just ignore your tkinter's GUI window.

When you do this then the windows manager now takes no any responsibility for your GUI window. Each and every task like window dragging, minimization and maximization, closing event etc should be handled by you manually.

Now to solve you dragging problem on windows taskbar there are two ways.

1) As I told you before that do everything manually, then you should to locate your windows taskbar manually and then modify your drag function to prevent your mouse motion after the borders of your taskbar.

2) The simplest way is to make your GUI window a top level window by which you will able to drag your window onto the taskbar without any window hiding problem.

To make the window top level you should just set an Attribute i.e. topmost = True.

```py
    root.attributes('-topmost',1)
```